# I would like to make details my default view in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10

As the title says I would like to make the details view my default view in File Explorer. I tried googling this but most results simply say to change it in folder properties but this seems to only apply it to the folder in question and usually its sub-folders. While researching previous questions on this subject on stack exchange I came across a few answers but they mostly concerned doing this on Windows XP/7 and involve editing the registry. So what I would like to know is if there is a way to do this on Windows 10 without editing the registry and if I need to edit the registry, what is the best method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

None of your googling mentioned **Apply to Folders**? That's surprising! That's the way you set a custom view for a give *FolderType*, the trick is to make sure you execute it once from each type o folder: General. Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos, Downloads.

[image]

Done properly, that covers all file system folders, but not Search Results, LIbraries, & other virtual folders. To set those to details you do need a registry mod. The following can be saved as a .reg file & merged to set Details as the default for all *FolderTypes*.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{0b0ba2e3-405f-415e-a6ee-cad625207853}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{24ccb8a6-c45a-477d-b940-3382b9225668}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4F01EBC5-2385-41f2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{51294DA1-D7B1-485b-9E9A-17CFFE33E187}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{654a1b99-8a4b-4e7b-a4e1-46378ad77a61}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{71D642A9-F2B1-42cd-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7F2F5B96-FF74-41da-AFD8-1C78A5F3AEA2}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{834d8a44-0974-4ed6-866e-f203d80b3810}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{8faf9629-1980-46ff-8023-9dceab9c3ee3}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{978e0ed7-92d6-4cec-9b59-3135b9c49ccf}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{982725ee-6f47-479e-b447-812bfa7d2e8f}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{B337FD00-9DD5-4635-A6D4-DA33FD102B7A}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{c1f8339f-f312-4c97-b1c6-ecdf5910c5c0}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{C4D98F09-6124-4fe0-9942-826416082DA9}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{da3f6866-35fe-4229-821a-26553a67fc18}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{DD61BD66-70E8-48dd-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{de2b70ec-9bf7-4a93-bd3d-243f7881d492}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9}]
"Mode"=dword:00000004
```

To clear previiously saved views that may not be in Detail view, copy & paste the following into a **PowerShell** window & press  to execute:

```
('BagMRU', 'Bags').ForEach({ri "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\$_" })
gps explorer | spps
```

Comment: That's what I meant by "folder properties but this seems to only apply it to the folder in question and usually its sub-folders". Thanks for explaining the registry edits, I didn't want mess around in the registry without knowing what I was doing.

Comment: Is there a list of which folder is represented by the UID, e.g. {3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd}.  Would be super useful.  I too want all search results in details view but don't want pictures, music, etc. to go to details view.

Comment: Here's a **PowerShell** one-liner to generate a list and save to a `.txt` file. Copy & paste this command into a **PowerShell** console window: `'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes' | gci | gp |select PSCHildName , CanonicalName | out-file FolderTypeList.txt`

Comment: Thanks Keith, that did it.